# Нужна ли запятая перед "словно" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая в предложении *"Этот шар вылетел из трубы словно ядро из пушки.*" перед *"словно"*?

И не попадает ли оно под это правило:

> Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях:
>   а) при сказуемом, требующем конкретизации (оборот имеет значение отождествления или приравнивания)

Answer (score 3):

Этот шар вылетел из трубы, словно ядро из пушки.

Это не оборот, а неполное сравнительное предложение с пропущенным сказуемым. Запятая ставится в обязательном порядке.

Например:

Гостиная набита гостями, как подушка пером. 
Высохшие стулья потрескивали, как дрова в камине. 
Дни отрываются от меня, как листики от дерева.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь оборот ведь отделен от сказуемого, поэтому запятая нужна. Сравнение, к тому же, налицо.